# Using maven in scripts or adding a script-runner task at the end

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm using maven on both mac and linux to build a `.war` file for a website.  I'd like to know the best way to automatically run a script that will deploy the website to the server after a build.

What I am currently doing is I have a `deploy.sh` script that will run

`mvn -P<PROFILE> clean package`

and will then do a bunch of ssh / scp stuff to copy the `target/file.war` to the web server and run a bunch of commands to start/stop tomcat - clean out the logs etc.

**Problems**

Although various stack posts say using `$?` is supposed to catch the error code from maven I have yet to get it working and if for some reason I have a bad maven build I have no way to detect it.  I would not like to do all my deploy tasks if the build fails.

#### Options?

1) Is there a correct way to detect a bad "build" from maven and have my script abort (I guess i could check if the war doesn't exist ...??)

2) Is there a maven "plugin" that will actually handle this for me, and if so could somebody provide a small code example.

Comment: Could you add the lines of code that attempts to catch the mvn exit code?

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things in the shell script which calls Maven and the deployment commands:

- test whether the WAR file exists before attempting to deploy it, as you suggest yourself;
- save Maven output to a timestamped log file for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using maven as the entry point to the deployment and let it call `deploy.sh` rather than the other way around. This way maven will fail the build if something goes wrong.

The Ant plugin should be able to help with this, take a look at the second example [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html). It allows you to run a script and fail on error if desired.